# How do I search with regex and avoid entries from a list?

Tags: python, regex

I have a long list of entries in a file in the following format:

`<space><space><number><space>"<word/phrase/sentence>"`

e.g.

`12345 = "Section 3 is ready for review"`

`24680 = "Bob to review Chapter 4"`

I need to find a way of inserting additional text at the beginning of the word/phrase/sentence, but only if it doesn't start with one of several key words.

Additional text: `'Complete: '`

List of key words: `key_words_list = ['Section', 'Page', Heading']`

e.g.

`12345 = "Section 3 is ready for review"` (no changes needed - sentence starts with 'Section' which is in the list)

`24680 = "Complete: Bob to review Chapter 4"` ('Complete: ' added to start of sentence because first word wasn't in list)

---

This could be done with a lot of string splitting and `if` statements but regex seems like it should be a more concise and much neater solution. I have the following that doesn't take account of the list:

```py
for line in lines:
    line = re.sub('(^\s\s[0-9]+\s=\s")', r'\1Complete: ', line)
```

I also have some code that manages to identify the lines that require changes:

```py
print([w for w in re.findall('^\s\s[0-9]+\s=\s"([\w+=?\s?,?.?]+)"', line) if w not in key_words_list])
```

Is regex the best option for what I need and if so, what am I missing?

---

Example inputs:

`12345 = "Section 3 is ready for review"`

`24680 = "Bob to review Chapter 4"`

Example outputs:

`12345 = "Section 3 is ready for review"`

`24680 = "Complete: Bob to review Chapter 4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```py
^\s{2}[0-9]+\s=\s"(?!(?:Section|Page|Heading)\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y11HMS/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s{2}` - two whitespaces
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `\s=\s` - a `=` enclosed with a single whitespace on both ends
- `"` - a `"` char
- `(?!(?:Section|Page|Heading)\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `Section`, `Page` or `Heading` whole word immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OZv5yk):

```py
import re
texts = ['  12345 = "Section 3 is ready for review"', '  24680 = "Bob to review Chapter 4"']
add = 'Complete: '
key_words_list = ['Section', 'Page', 'Heading']
pattern = re.compile(fr'^\s{{2}}[0-9]+\s=\s"(?!(?:{"|".join(key_words_list)})\b)')
for text in texts:
    print(pattern.sub(fr'\g<0>{add}', text))

# =>   12345 = "Section 3 is ready for review"
#      24680 = "Complete: Bob to review Chapter 4"
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Nice and concise and far neater than what I currently have. Thank you!